# MySql - Add new row for every userId in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Below is the table i am trying to write a query for to add new rows for every user.

[image]

My question is how do i add a new row for every user? Which means for userId 2 I add AccId 4 and similarly for 7 and 8. Since there is no concept of for loop in sql, do i make use of while? If so, how to loop through the userIds since the IDs are not in equal increments?

Comment: `Insert Into mytable (UserID, AccID) Select UserID, 4 From MyTable Group By UserID`

Comment: loops are for procedure languages, not set languages

Comment: Whoever down voted, please leave a reason for down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this maybe:

```
Insert Into mytable (UserID, AccID) 
Select UserID, max(accId)+1 
From MyTable 
Group By UserID
```

You can re-run it every time, you will create the next value.

Answer (score 0):

Untested on a MySql server:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( ID, AccId )
SELECT MyValues.ID, MyValues.Espr1
FROM (SELECT MyTable.ID, Max([AccId]+1) AS Espr1
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.ID)  AS MyValues;
```

Basically we prefetch Id a AccId grouping the values of Id and grabbing the Max of AccId.
Then we add these rows to the main table. Repeating the query we will add the value 5 (AccId) and so on, always adding 1